# How to change value of global variable in a function?

Tags: python, function, raspberry-pi

I got a code from the internet for my project, and there is a function with parameter that i need to make change of global variable value

it is a flask request json app, i use the ifttt to send json to this project. i've tried to change by this code but it won't change, the X always in 1

```
X=1
@app.route('/',methods=['POST'])
def index():
    req = request.get_json(silent=True, force=True)
    val = processRequest(req)
    #print(val)
    r = make_response(json.dumps(val))
    r.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    return r
def processRequest(req):
    device = req['device']
    state = json.loads(req['state'])
    #print(state)
    if (device=='bedlamp'):  
       global()['X']=int(30)
```

i want it when the ifttt send device bedlamp, the value of global variable turn to 30, can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

To change a global variable called X inside a function you have to do:

1) bring the variable into the function scope

```
global X
```

2) change its value

```
X = 30
```

so:

```
def abc():
    global x
    x = 30
```

Comment: I've tried that too, but i think that code only work for normal function (without parameter)

Comment: @RaymondAnthony No, this code is correct. If you're running a webserver there might be multiple processes however, and the module-globals are local to your process.

Comment: I see, but why i can't update the value of my global in another script? I use the x as global variable, so i can use x as the value in another script. In another script i use import nameofscript.py then nameofscript.x , but the value in there always 1?

Comment: @RaymondAnthony you could have said that before. you should do `from nameofscript import x` OR `import nameofscript` and then `nameofscript.x`

Comment: So if the x value in first script change, will it change too in the second script?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `global` keyword, like this:

```
def processRequest(req):
    device = req['device']
    state = json.loads(req['state'])
    if (device=='bedlamp'):
        global X
        X = 30
```